# Label Position, Resize Background And Hide Title Bar

Tags: python, pyglet

I'm trying to better understand Pyglet and I'm using a script posted by Torxed in my previous question. I started to modify it until I reached this point:

```
import pyglet, datetime, os
from pyglet.gl import *
from collections import OrderedDict
from time import time
from pathlib import Path

key = pyglet.window.key

class main(pyglet.window.Window):

    #Variable Display
    Fullscreen = False
    CountDisplay = 0
    setDisplay0 = (1024, 576)
    setDisplay1 = (800, 600)
    setDisplay2 = (1024, 768)
    setDisplay3 = (1280, 720)
    setDisplay4 = (1280, 1024)
    setDisplay5 = (1366, 768)
    setDisplay6 = (1920, 1080)

    #Variable Info
    infoHidden = False
    title = "Pokémon Life And Death: Esploratori Del Proprio Destino"
    build = "Versione: 0.0.0"
    keyPrint = "Nessuno"
    MousekeyPrint = "Nessuno"
    infoFullscreen = "Disattivo"
    infoDisplay = "1024, 576"

    def __init__ (self, width=1024, height=576, fullscreen=False, *args, **kwargs):
        super(main, self).__init__(width, height, fullscreen, *args, **kwargs)

        platform = pyglet.window.get_platform()
        display = platform.get_default_display()
        screen = display.get_default_screen()
        self.infoScreen = (screen.width, screen.height)

        self.xDisplay = int(screen.width / 2 - self.width / 2)
        self.yDisplay = int(screen.height / 2 - self.height / 2)
        self.set_location(self.xDisplay, self.yDisplay)

        self.sprites = OrderedDict()
        self.spritesInfo = OrderedDict()

        #Information Hidden
        #Title
        self.spritesInfo["title_label"] = pyglet.text.Label(self.title, x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 0))
        #Build Version
        self.spritesInfo["build_label"] = pyglet.text.Label(self.build, x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 20))
        #Fullscreen
        self.spritesInfo["fullscreen_label"] = pyglet.text.Label("Fullscreen: " + self.infoFullscreen, x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 40))
        #Display
        self.spritesInfo["screen_label"] = pyglet.text.Label("Display: " + self.infoDisplay, x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 60))
        #FPS
        self.spritesInfo["fps_label"] = pyglet.text.Label("FPS: 0", x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 80))
        self.last_update = time()
        self.fps_count = 0
        #Mouse Position
        self.mouse_x = 0
        self.mouse_y = 0
        self.spritesInfo["mouse_label"] = pyglet.text.Label(("Mouse Position (X,Y): " + str(self.mouse_x) + "," + str(self.mouse_y)), x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 100))
        #Player Position
        self.player_x = 0
        self.player_y = 0
        self.spritesInfo["player_label"] = pyglet.text.Label(("Player Position (X,Y): " + str(self.player_x) + "," + str(self.player_y)), x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 120))
        #Key Press
        self.keys = OrderedDict()
        self.spritesInfo["key_label"] = pyglet.text.Label(("Key Press: " + self.keyPrint), x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 140))
        #Mouse Press
        self.spritesInfo["MouseKey_label"] = pyglet.text.Label(("Mouse Key Press: " + self.MousekeyPrint), x=self.infoPos("x", 0), y=self.infoPos("y", 160))

        self.alive = 1

    def infoPos(self, object, ny):
        posInfo = self.get_size()
        if object is "x":
            elab = 10
        elif object is "y":
            elab = posInfo[1] - 20 - ny
        else:
            elab = 0
        return elab

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        self.mouse_x = x
        self.mouse_y = y

    def on_mouse_release(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        self.MousekeyPrint = "Nessuno"

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        self.MousekeyPrint = str(button)

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, button, modifiers):
        self.drag = True
        print('Dragging mouse at {}x{}'.format(x, y))

    def on_key_release(self, symbol, modifiers):
        self.keyPrint = "Nessuno"
        try:
            del self.keys[symbol]
        except:
            pass

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE:
            self.alive = 0
        if symbol == key.F2:
            datanow = datetime.datetime.now()
            if not Path("Screenshot").is_dir():
                os.makedirs("Screenshot")
            pyglet.image.get_buffer_manager().get_color_buffer().save("Screenshot/"+str(datanow.day)+"-"+str(datanow.month)+"-"+str(datanow.year)+"_"+str(datanow.hour)+"."+str(datanow.minute)+"."+str(datanow.second)+".png")
        if symbol == key.F3:
            if self.infoHidden:
                self.infoHidden = False
            else:
                self.infoHidden = True
        if symbol == key.F10:
            self.CountDisplay += 1
            if self.CountDisplay == 1:
                size = self.setDisplay1
            elif self.CountDisplay == 2:
                size = self.setDisplay2
            elif self.CountDisplay == 3:
                size = self.setDisplay3
            elif self.CountDisplay == 4:
                size = self.setDisplay4
            elif self.CountDisplay == 5:
                size = self.setDisplay5
            elif self.CountDisplay == 6:
                size = self.setDisplay6
            else:
                self.CountDisplay = 0
                size = self.setDisplay0

            self.set_size(size[0], size[1])
            self.infoDisplay = str(size[0]) + "," + str(size[1])
            pos = (int(self.infoScreen[0] / 2 - size[0] / 2), int(self.infoScreen[1] / 2 - size[1] / 2))
            self.set_location(pos[0], pos[1])
        if symbol == key.F11:
            if self.Fullscreen:
                self.Fullscreen = False
                self.set_fullscreen(False)
                self.infoFullscreen = "Disattivo"
            else:
                self.Fullscreen = True
                self.set_fullscreen(True)
                self.infoFullscreen = "Attivo"

        self.keyPrint = str(symbol)
        self.keys[symbol] = True

    def pre_render(self):
        pass

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        #FPS
        self.fps_count += 1
        if time() - self.last_update > 1:
            self.spritesInfo["fps_label"].text = "FPS: " + str(self.fps_count)
            self.fps_count = 0
            self.last_update = time()
        #Mouse Position
        self.spritesInfo["mouse_label"].text = "Mouse Position (X,Y): " + str(self.mouse_x) + "," + str(self.mouse_y)
        #Player Position
        self.spritesInfo["player_label"].text = "Player Position (X,Y): " + str(self.player_x) + "," + str(self.player_y)
        #Key Press
        self.spritesInfo["key_label"].text = "Key Press: " + self.keyPrint
        #Mouse Press
        self.spritesInfo["MouseKey_label"].text = "Mouse Key Press: " + self.MousekeyPrint
        #Fullscreen
        self.spritesInfo["fullscreen_label"].text = "Fullscreen: " + self.infoFullscreen
        #Display
        self.spritesInfo["screen_label"].text = "Display: " + self.infoDisplay

        #self.bg.draw()
        self.pre_render()

        for sprite in self.sprites:
            self.sprites[sprite].draw()

        if self.infoHidden:
            for spriteInfo in self.spritesInfo:
                self.spritesInfo[spriteInfo].draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            event = self.dispatch_events()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    x = main()
    x.run()
```

But now I find myself in front of a point where I can not proceed in Pyglet alone.

I can not understand how I can change the coordinates of the "label" every time the window size changes.

I would like to be able to use an image as a background and adapt it to the size of the window (basic the image is 1920x1080, ie the maximum window size). The problem is that I did not find much on this subject. I state that what I'm working on is 2D, not 3D. I had found a possible solution in another question, always answered by Torxed on the resizing of an image, but in some tests before this, after having adapted it, it did not work. So I do not know where to bang my head sincerely. In Pygame it was easy to use "pygame.transform.scale", but in Pyglet I would not know.

Finally, I tried both on the Pyglet wiki and on the web, but I did not find anything. How can I delete or hide the window title bar? In Pygame, you could with the flags. Is it possible to do this also with Pyglet?

EDIT:
I forgot to ask another question. When I press a key on the keyboard or mouse, the information displayed with F3 is printed in the corresponding key number. Is there a way to replace the number with the name of the button? For example, 97 is replaced with "A"? Obviously, I mean if there's a way without having to list all the keys and put the "if" statement for everyone.

EDIT2:
It seems like the script posted, the `def on_resize (self, width, height)` part does not like it very much. Let me explain, if for itself the function works correctly. The problem is that if I insert it, the labels, once pressed F3, do not appear. I tried to test it using `print` in several places and it seems that the only instruction that is not executed is `self.spritesInfo [spriteInfo] .draw ()`

Comment: Three quick answers for you: `on_resize(self, width, height)` and do `self.spritesInfo["screen_label"].x = width/2` for instance. Regarding `97 -> 'a'`, do `if symbol >= 65 or symbol <= 122: chr(symbol)` :)

Comment: Oh, and regarding `pygame.transform.scale`, in pyglet it's the same. You do `self.spritesInfo["screen_label"].scale = 2` and it will become twice as big. You calculate this by doing `self.spritesInfo["screen_label"].scale = window_width/img_width` and that should give you the scale needed to adapt the width (note that height might need to be calculate as well if the aspect ratio of the image isn't the same as the window)

Comment: I can formulate a proper answer in a few hours, but here's two good sources of references on the pyglet wiki: https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/window/event/pyglet.window.event.WindowEventLogger.html#pyglet.window.event.WindowEventLogger and https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/window/pyglet.window.Window.html#pyglet.window.Window for the window. https://pyglet.readthedocs.io/en/pyglet-1.2-maintenance/api/pyglet/sprite/pyglet.sprite.Sprite.html for the sprite (`sprite.x` for instance is a attribute you can change).

Comment: First of all, I thank you very much for your help. Regarding the location of the label, I had read on the wiki how to do, but I did not understand when to use it and here, in your answer, you pointed out that I had completely lost "on_resize ()" as a function called the window :)